# Error Adding to 9.9 in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add floats to get 9.9, anyway when I run this code:
3.3 + 3.3 + 3.3, The end result is 9.899999999999999
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Don't worry about it, that's just an artifact of how floating-point arithmetic works. The way to "fix" it is to format your numbers correctly when you print them.

Comment: How would i go about forming them correctly?

Comment: @L.And, go through the answers of the questions marked as duplicates. You'll find many useful answers to your question *How would i go about forming them correctly?*

Comment: As Keyur said, there are various options, depending on what you want. If you only want one digit after the decimal point you can do `n = 3.3 + 3.3 + 3.3; print('{:.1f}'.format(n))`